# How to debug: ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: django, django-models, error-handling, django-views, django-templates

I am now trying to debug this error in django for ages. Is someone able to help me? The reason for this error is that I am doing a successful ajax call, however, then at the end the error is thrown. Please see:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59734)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "4_Code/Floq_Django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "Floq_Django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi @markwalker_ 
I am updating a database model field with the ajax call. Everything is successfully, as when I am 'manually' refreshing the page after this error occurred, all changes are done...the problem is that I have to manually refresh as I get this error

Comment: And what's on port 59734? It'd probably be most helpful to add all the related code.